# Hold a parameter in @RestController available for the whole class or even application instead of copypasting the same code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-restcontroller

Let's say that I have a few @RestController classes in my app.

I am getting one specific parameter from the OAuth2Authentication context. A sample request is looking like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/contractor")
public Contractor contractor(OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    String email = String.valueOf(((LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) authentication.getUserAuthentication().getDetails()).get("email"));
    return contractorRepository.findByEmail(email);
}
```

It is working as a charm, but there is one problem. There is a bunch of endpoints basing on the `OAuth2Authentication` object, precisely - on the email string from

```
String.valueOf(((LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) authentication.getUserAuthentication().getDetails()).get("email"));
```

I don't understand the Spring Security nor OAuth2 too well, but is there a way to somehow autowire this `OAuth2Authentication` and hold the `String email` as a field in the Rest controllers, or hold it in a separate class and inject it into the controllers?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works with `OAuth2Authentication` but you can give it a try.

You can use the `SecurityContextHolder` of `spring-security` to get the `Authentication` object like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/contractor")
public Contractor contractor() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    ...
}
```